# Setting system email address and sender name in multi config

Tags: config, emails, configuration

Is there a way to set the system email address and sender name from within the config file?

This would be useful when using multi environment configurations. For instance, during development or on my staging server I wish emails to be sent to me (the developer). While for production they would go to the site owner.

I can see the values in serialised data within the database but was hoping I could override them within the config file. I've tried the  keys "emailAddress" and "senderName" to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [testToEmailAddress](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#testToEmailAddress) config setting which

> Configures Craft to send all system emails to a single email address (or multiple email addresses), for testing purposes.

sounds like the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

[Marion's answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/15636/57) is a workaround for Craft 2, but this has been officially addressed in the upcoming Craft 3:  https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/840

Comment: This feedback 404s. Is this possible yet in the config? It would be a great feature.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Shameless plug: We've written a plugin that automatically updates your email settings depending on your environment. It's not free, but it is cheap :-) Please [check out](http://red-robot.co.uk/our-work/email-settings-craft-cms-plug-in) the page on our website for more information.